# Storing data files for Heroku Django app on S3

Tags: python, django, heroku, tensorflow, amazon-s3

I am attempting to deploy a web demo for a trained neural network on Heroku. I am having some trouble with this because the underlying Tensorflow model that needs to be loaded is about 900MB, which is too large to deploy in a Git commit with the code. I need a way to deploy this model file along with my code because of Heroku's ephemeral file system.

I hacked together a solution where, only on the first received request, the server downloads the model files from an Amazon S3 bucket. I threw this code in the body of the Django `views.py` file. However, this still isn't working because the first request is timing out on the Heroku server. Is there anywhere else I can put this code or a cleaner way to approach the problem?

EDIT: just to be clear, the file only needs to be loaded once every time the server runs

Comment: Use `django-storages` with it's S3 backend for file storage? You're probably not going to get around the issue of loading a 900mb file though. Websites just shouldn't do that unless it's a file download of course.

Comment: It feels like there should be some way to save a trained model on the backend file system...

Comment: Update: I've gotten my slug size down to 520MB, which is still slightly larger than the maximum size of 500MB. Hoping to make the model slightly smaller in order to deploy it.